# Android: ClassCastException Adding HeaderView to Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am getting `ClassCastException` when i try to add `HeaderView` to `ListView` here is the code of `HeaderView`

```
 View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, null);
 listview.addHeaderView(headerView);
 listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and here is the `stackTrace`

```
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1468)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-25 12:38:42.324: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
```

**EDIT:**

This is my Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/re3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
             >
        </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my Activity code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.lay);

    ListView listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this,l, list_cons);

    View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, null);

    listview.addHeaderView(headerView);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your codes ?

Comment: what should I post more?

Comment: @user3294034 what you want to do with the code, post your this much code that we can understand it and help you out.

Comment: Post Activity and layout files.

Comment: I want to add a header to the top of ListView this is my need.

Comment: Are you sure, you're not altering anything layout-related in getView method of your adapter? Your code seems fine and the exception you're getting can be thrown while layouting any row, not only header. Is your list working without header?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:** as @Zielony pointed out, the previous solution would attach your header to your list as a child, and you don't want that. Here is what you can do to inflate properly your `layout_*` attributes without attaching the header:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_header, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

---

Try to specify the parent for the view you inflate. Replace this:

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, null);
```

By this:

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, listview);
```

This should set the LayoutParams to the right type, not causing the `ClassCastException` anymore.

Comment: this will also add header to the ListView as a child. ListView uses special type of adapter for lists with headers and footers

Comment: You sure of that? I think the ViewGroup parameter is here only for inflation purposes, to properly determine the `layout_*` parameters type.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. See: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#500

Answer (score -1):

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerView,null);
ls.addHeaderView(header);
```

In my case, this works

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
setListAdapter(new
ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,android.R.id.text1, names));
```